# MySQL single master with multiple databases replicating on multiple slaves

Tags: mysql, database, replication

Well i'm just checking but i guess i've commited a mistake.

I've a single MySQL server instance running wich contains several databases.

What i need is to replicate each of these databases to a diferent slave.

more clearly:

```
DB1 on Server1 replicates on Slave1
DB2 on Server1 replicates on Slave2
...
DBn on Server1 replicates on Slave'n
```

*Meaning Server1 = single MySQL instance.

So what are the options?

1. Create multiple instances of master/server and replicate then with
   its corresponding slave?

   ```
   [DB1 on Server1 replicates on Slave1]
   [DB2 on Server2 replicates on Slave2]...
   ```
2. Replicate all the databases on the bin.log and filter then on slave
   configuration?
3. Is it possible to setup several bin.logs on the same server for each slave?

Without the above three is there another (better) aproach?

Thx.

Comment: See this on the MySQL site: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/replication-solutions-partitioning.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- Approach #1 would require much more work and maintenance.
- Approach #3 is not possible AFAIK.
- I would then go for the approach #2: single master, several slaves, with binlog filtering on each slave.

Each slave would have, in its `my.cnf` file, the following filter:

```
replicate-wild-do-table = DBn.%
```

See: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/replication-solutions-partitioning.html

Comment: Ok thanks. thats exactly what i need. But unfornately i've already a slave linked to this master and the server was configured using `binlog-do-db=db1` so, should i stop my production and start a new bin-log? How do i setup the master to replicate all schemas?

Comment: Yes, I suggest to restart your master with a binlog logging everything, by simply putting `log_bin=ON` (or `=1`) in the master's `my.cnf`. Using `binlog-do-db` option is dangerous, see http://www.mysqlperformanceblog.com/2009/05/14/why-mysqls-binlog-do-db-option-is-dangerous/

Comment: ok setting now on production. Indeed i've choose to use `binlog-do-db` to each schema but setting also slaves with `replicate-wild-do-table` to avoid most of the dangerous part. thx guys.